# Was Judas a partaker of the feet washing by Jesus?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-john, judas-iscariot

When Jesus washed his disciples feet in John 13, did he wash Judas' feet as well? If he did, does this not mean that Judas has a part in the salvation of Christ?

> John 13:8:  Peter saith unto him, Thou shalt never wash my feet. Jesus answered him, If I wash thee not, thou hast no part with me.

Well except that verse 27-30 happened before the washing of the feet...

> John 13:27:  And after the sop Satan entered into him. Then said Jesus unto him, That thou doest, do quickly.

Comment: It seems to me that you have answered your own question.

Comment: From which denominational perspective do you wish your answer?  Many denominations and traditions are represented here, and they don't always agree.  Thanks!

Comment: @JBH, I believe the gospel should and will get to a point where every christian believes exactly the same thing. Eph 4:13. Please i expect answers to be from proper exegesis not biased to any denomination because the word of God shouldn't be open to private interpretations/ opinions.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I've been out of town.  I understand, but until the world actually gets to the point of a unity of the faith, there will be differences of opinion.  Mac's answer wasn't bad, but because there isn't clarity in the scriptural text (hence the need to ask your question) it was, by definition, a private interpretation.  I suspect that only an answer from an angel or God Himself meets the expectation of "proper exegesis" as any answer by a mortal is always a private interpretation.  Thus, this website's expectation that a denominational perspective be provided.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in John 13:5 to exclude Judas from the foot washing.  (This was part-way through the meal, v2.)

Further, it is when the foot washing was complete (v21) that Jesus begins to tell the disciples some final truths, including that one of them was about to betray the Messiah.

Therefore, I see no need to re-arrange the order of the events as portrayed in John 13.  Even if the rite of bread and wine came after Judas left, the fact that someone participates in the communion, or not, does not guarantee their salvation (or otherwise)as Judas clearly rejected Christ's offer.

Thus, John 13 records that Judas had Jesus wash his feet, but Matt 26:25, 26 might imply (without saying) that Judas left before the rite of bread and wine.  However, Luke 22:14-23 might also imply that it was after the rite of bread and wine that Judas left.

Comment: in addition; Neither foot washing or partaking of communion is a part of salvation. Those are both acts of love and it is to be remembered that God is love, and Jesus loved even Judas enough to die for his sins.